# How to horizontally scale multiple azure cloud services

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-cloud-services

I have two small size azure cloud service seperately and need to scaled this. How would we do this?

Using Load Balancer or something else

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can just scale the current Cloud Service to run multiple instances: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale#manual-scale

Comment: I have multiple cloud service not multiple instance so in this case how could we achieve this? please suggest.

Comment: Both cloud services will need to be scaled separately. Scaling horizontally means adding more instances. So, the link that Mikkel provided is appropriate. Azure will automatically load balance your requests (using the internal load balancer). However, if you want to share the load between these your two cloud services, please look at Azure Traffic Manager (ATM) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview